# highlighting parts of pgfpie in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgf-pie

I was wondering if there was a way to highlight a section of a pgfpie pie graph in a Beamer presentation.

One way I managed to make it work was to copy the entire figure, change the color of the desired section and use `\only` to first show the version with the original color, and then the version with the changed color, but that's quite an impractical way of doing it.

Here is a sample pgfpie graph:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator={\,},
}
\def\ScanPercentage#1\afternumber{\SI{#1}{\percent}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Pie Chart}
    \begin{figure}
      \scriptsize
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[color={blue, red}, rotate=-35, before number=\ScanPercentage, after  number ={ }\%,]{91.2/Muži, 8.8/Ženy}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the **multido** package:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{multido}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator={\,},
}
\def\ScanPercentage#1\afternumber{\SI{#1}{\percent}}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Pie Chart}
    \multido{\n=1+1}{2}{
      \only<\n>{
        \begin{figure}
          \scriptsize
          \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pie[color={\ifnum\n=1 blue\else yellow\fi, red}, rotate=-35, before number=\ScanPercentage, after  number ={ }\%,]{91.2/Muži, 8.8/Ženy}
          \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
      }
    }
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```